# How to install ubuntu server without display

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh

I have an E3 server. But the display port on it doesn't work. I have tried to plug the hard drive to another computer to install, but it won't boot. When I try to install ubuntu on it through netboot. But I can even not get into BIOS settings because I have no display. So I wonder if there's an image that when I flash it into the hard drive on my server, it can finish the installation by itself. If that image doesn't exist, can I install ubuntu through ssh?